# Connection string for exe file in c#

Tags: c#

I am new in c# programming. Recently i developed a desktop app and create exe file for this. But it is not run in another pc. Here my app.config file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="newConnectionString"
          connectionString="Data Source=.\SqlExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Asset_Management_System.mdf; Integrated Security=True;User Instance =True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Please help me.

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Your connection string points to a local file, did you move the file to the other machine?

Comment: You need to post the code where the error occurs as well as the error message itself otherwise it will be difficult to help you

Comment: 1. the other machine needs to install Sql Express. 2. the other machine needs to have the local mdf file (but I would just make a new database instead of loading mdf)

Answer (score -1):

Build the project in a release state (Build>Configuration Manager> Active Solution configuration). It is going to create a Release Folder inside the "BIN" folder, which would contain all the files need to execute the program. If you make reference to others files, they should be contained there too, so put them on that folder.  This folder can be carried to others PC running windows with ".NET Framework" installed and the application should run fine. Also, you can create an installer by deployment technologies like Click Once, that would do stuff like Install all the dependencies automatically (.Net Framework, visual C++ etc.) and special configuration or settings.

Comment: The .exe alone may not have the necessary libraries to run your application. You also need the DLL, metadata files etc. They all are going to be included in the Release Folder.

Comment: It is clear OP uses sql express. It will NOT be included even if you built it under release build

Comment: @Steve you are right. That sort of things should be included inside the deployment technology you choose to use.